# foreach loop with link to 'this' in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

There is the following code:

```
  User.prototype.convertFromPermissionsToScopes = ->
    this.scopes = {}
    scopesNames = ['create', 'delete', 'update', 'show']
    for groupName of this.permissions
      this.scopes[groupName] = {}
      scopesNames.forEach (scopeName) ->
        this.scopes[groupName][scopeName] = this.permissions[groupName].indexOf(scopeName) isnt -1
```

I got the error 'this.scopes is undefined' at the last line. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: My guess (not having used Coffee, but how different can it be) is that `this` changes context when you pass it into the `forEach`. You'll need to save a reference to it and use that instead. People normally use `self` or `_this`.

Comment: Why do you use a `forEach` call at all instead of a simple `for of` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) to pass the outer `this` to the context of the `forEach`:

```
scopesNames.forEach (scopeName) =>
```

That will ensure the outer scope is passed to the context of the method.

---

Just a sidenote you can use `::` for `prototype` and `@` for `this`:

```
User::convertFromPermissionsToScopes = ->
  @scopes = {}
  scopesNames = ['create', 'delete', 'update', 'show']
  for groupName of @permissions
    @scopes[groupName] = {}
    scopesNames.forEach (scopeName) =>
      @scopes[groupName][scopeName] = @permissions[groupName].indexOf(scopeName) isnt -1
```